# SWIG Python cast from parent to child object

Tags: python, swig

I'm trying to use the python bindings (swig bindings) for the libyui package.

When receiving an event response, libyui always returns a parent object of type YEvent, and YEvent has a eventType() function that tells you which type of child class this is. I need to be able to cast the parent type to the child type, in order to read properties of the child object.
Here's a sample of what I've tried (d is a dialog created by YUI.widgetFactory):

```
event = d.waitForEvent()
if event.eventType() == yui.YEvent.WidgetEvent:
    event.__class__ = yui.YWidgetEvent
    ret['EventReason'] = event.toString(event.reason())ret['EventReason'] = event.toString(event.reason())
```

I thought that casting the parent python type to the child python type would allow me to call the child functions (event.reason()), but this fails with:

TypeError: in method 'YWidgetEvent_reason', argument 1 of type 'YWidgetEvent const *'

Since the only argument to the function is the YWidgetEvent, it seems to be failing because YWidgetEvent is not a YEvent (although it is a child of this type).

So, in general, how do you with SWIG python bindings, cast between object types? Is this possible?

Comment: Please, why do you tag this question as C? IMHO it has nothing to do with C (possibly with C++, but not with C) and no C/C++ code is shown to be able to discuss about it.  Please, remove the C tag from the question.

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking of the fact that I was using the Python c API to try and solve this.

Comment: Also, I've worked out a solution (will post shortly). Essentially, I built a c++ function which accepts a YEvent object as a parameter then casts it to a YWidgetEvent, then I built that function using swig, and call it in my Python code to do the cast for me. Would be nice if I could avoid this mess though.